# SubversionEdge and Powergui: ViewVC shows BOM

Tags: encoding, subversion-edge

I am trying to set up SVN repository and since we are limited to Windows as server system here, I chose SubversionEdge as SVN/ViewVC solution.

Unfortunately for some reason all files that are created by PowerGUI and submitted using TortoiseSVN are shown with BOM at the beginning (using IE 9)

[image]

Clearly this is due to the encoding being misinterpreted at some point.
If I convert encoding for the file to ANSI using external tool, the BOM disappears. I cannot find any option in PowerGUI go set default coding to ANSI ( not that is a proper solution either)

Has anyone had this issue or knows what do I need to change?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug.

One solution is to set "detect_encoding = 1" in your viewvc.conf